# Edit a file from terminal by Openoffice

Tags: file, terminal, edit

I'm trying to open a file in Openoffice from terminal and to automatically replace a string with another one given as parameter. Can I use a macro or something similar?
Please tell me it's possible.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean an ODF file, then ODF files are mostly zipped XML. You can use your favourite scripting language to unzip it, replace the string in the relevant file, and rezip it. [Here is the ODF spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/12572/OpenDocument-v1.0-os.pdf). [Here is a Python example](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9347).

Comment: Thank you! Now I use a Find and replace macro, launched by terminal with arguments... but your idea worths an accepted answer and maybe a try :)